# How to add in this case elements to the ArrayList

Tags: java, android-studio, arraylist

i am runing the Code below but not happens. How can i doit right?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    LocationManager locationManager;
    LocationListener locationListener;
    List<String> memorablePlaces;
    ListView listView;
}


@Override

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        listView =  findViewById(R.id.memorablePlaces);

        memorablePlaces = new ArrayList<>();

        memorablePlaces.add("Add a place");

        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);

        listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass your list to adapter:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, memorablePlaces);
```

Comment: TX! I missed something